How do you increase the starting memory and allocation rate of a Ruby process?
I am running an MRI Ruby 3.3.3 script that starts by creating an array of 15 million unique(ish) items. (I am simulating some data stream processing). The process starts with ~350 MB, and then starts to grow by 100MB/s, taking nearly 1 minute to load all those objects into memory. JRuby, however, does this in a matter of seconds, aggressively increasing its process size much, much faster than 100MB/s.
How can I increase the allocation rate and/or initial allocation of memory for the Ruby process?
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bmbm(40) do |x|
  size = 15_000_000
  stream_a = nil
  stream_b = nil

  x.report "Dual array creation of #{size} hashes" do
    stream_a = Array.new(size) { |i| { id: rand(size * 10), handle: "foo#{rand(size)}" } }
    stream_b = Array.new(size) { |i| { id: rand(size * 10), age: rand(100) % 40 } }
  end
end

# .rbenv/versions/3.3.3/bin/bundle exec ruby
# user     system      total        real
# Dual array creation of 15000000 hashes    12.875903  28.690656  41.566559 ( 42.643869)

# jruby -J-Xmx24576M"
# user     system      total        real
# Dual array creation of 15000000 hashes    15.710000   1.850000  17.560000 (  5.435642)

I've tried increasing nearly all the RUBY_GC_X environment variables but with no luck. Either I'm not trying the right ones or the values I'm putting in are wrong or not accepted.

Increasing memory size doesn't take that long. I guess it is loading the records and updating the data structure that takes so long. What does the code look like that loads the records into memory?

Can you post the array creation part?

When running Array.new(10_000_000) { |i| "foo#{i}" } I can't see any significant difference between MRI and JRuby (MRI is even faster). That's why I'm asking how you create that array. I assume that something else is going on. Maybe the data stream that you mentioned?

Debugging details will definitely be required to determine the why but they may also assist us in providing alternate solutions as loading "several million unique items" into an Array in memory is likely very inefficient and may not be the best option, depending on the usage and implementation.

I posted the code.

How have you determined that memory allocation is the issue?

CRuby increases allocations in chunks. While you could fool around with the amount of increase, a better way of doing it would be to allocate the Array size when you instantiate the Array using a sensible default value or nil, so it does it in one operation. Then you can assign to the Array as needed.
Cache warming and memory operations aren't really what Ruby (esp. YARV) is optimized for, but since CRuby runs on a single core having to continually walk or modify the size of an Array will be more expensive than creating it all at once. YMMV by interpreter engine.

You're doing three things here: 1) You're iterating, which is slower than if you just make a single allocation; and 2) you're performing operations inside a loop that take non-zero time; and 3) you're actually using randomness inside your loops, so that adds time and memory too. You have to make speed or memory trade-offs, and if you really want to join millions of records you're probably better off doing that in a database or NoSQL key/value store anyway. Allocating and munging millions of records shouldn't be a Ruby loop; use SQL, Redis, or MongoDB instead.

Running your benchmarks with Ruby 3.3.3 and JRuby 9.2.14.0 on macOS 14.5 on a 2018 Macbook Pro 2.7 Ghz i7, here's some simple observations by running top while the benchmarks run.

JRuby uses a lot more memory. > 20+ GB vs < 10 GB.
JRuby uses multiple cores, MRI Ruby does not.

I think all your benchmarking is that JRuby will use multiple cores to run the benchmark in parallel, but it's a memory hog. You can potentially recover this in MRI Ruby by using several Ractors, one or two for every core, to load data in parallel.
